# Is it possible to change the ARKit scene's object when clicking on a button Swift

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, scnscene, arscnview

I am building and ARkit project for the first time, and what I need to do is to, first of all, I have to display a 3D Sphere in the ARSCNView. and then when I click on a button, the sphere should disappear and display a 3D cube at its place.

I was thinking about it ad that my code :

```
 @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    var  objectNode: SCNNode?
    var objectScene: SCNScene?

objectScene = SCNScene(named: "sphere.dae")
objectNode = objectScene!.rootNode
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(objectNode!)
```

and here is the code for the button:

```
@IBAction func cubeButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
          sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
            node.removeFromParentNode()
        }
        
        objectScene = SCNScene(named: "cube.dae")    
        objecteNode = objectScene!.rootNode
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(objecteNode!) 
    }
```

and I am facing this error

```
[SceneKit] Error: removing the root node of a scene from its scene is not allowed
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was missing in my above code is that I had to make the deletion and add two synchronize tasks. Since the Delete function is into a closure( asynchronous task). so the add function will be executed before the deletion.
And by then the error will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the error tells exactly what's causing it.

Editted --- try one of the two following ways

- Use the following code to avoid removing `pointOfView` which is your `SCNCamera`.

```
sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
    if node == sceneView.pointOfView {return}
    node.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

- If you only have one node to remove, which in your case is `sphereNode`, there's no need to use enumerate method. Simply hold a reference to that node, and remove if when you'd like to.

```
sphereNode.removeFromParentNode()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @kevinn-w, but it doesn't really solve my problem 
I am still looking for a solution

Comment: Hello @Elin, can you try the two methods in my updated answer?

Comment: Hello @Kevinn W, thank you for your help, 
I actually figure out my problem. 
which is: I was trying to add a new node before the other one is deleted, since the delete function in into a closure so it is an async task, that's why I added some code so the Add functionality will be working just after the closure finishes its work. 
it does make sense right?

Comment: Yes @Elin. You do need to make sure the node is deleted before add new stuff. I'm curious why you have to use `enumerated`, can't you just remove that node before creating a new node?